# pandas df.loc returns blank df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm sure I'm making an obviously mistake, but can't see it.

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id year plan grade prior_grade
21 2017 text A     B
56 2015 text B     B
43 2016 text A     C
```

and want to create a new df with only those rows where prior_grade = c.  I'm using this to do so:

```
prior_c = (df.loc[(df['prior_grade']=='C')])
```

which returns an empty df (column names print but no rows when calling `prior_c.head()`)

Again, I'm sure I'm making an obvious mistake, but just can't see it.

edit: also tried with less parens and got the same result:

```
prior_c = df.loc[df['prior_grade']=='C']
```

Comment: This worked for me.  You should check for extra spaces.  Use df.to_dict to look for make some extras spaces in your dataframe.

Comment: I'm not seeing extra spaces.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get a data-frame with a single row, the one where prior-grade is C, just as you'd expect.

Comment: Ok - I must have done something when I created the df that means my data is behaving unexpectedly.

Comment: also, you dont need to use .loc[], this works too: df[df['prior_grade']=='C']

Answer (score 0):

This should work, although I believe you should make a copy of the dataframe.  This serves to explicitly make the new dataframe a copy (rather than a view of the original) so as to avoid unintentionally changing your original df.  I would recommend the following:

`prior_c = df.loc[df['prior_grade']=='C'].copy()`